# ERROR: METSVC: Cannot open the service manager(0x00000005)

Tags: metasploit

When an exploit is run the run metsvc command gives an error stating that it cannot open the service manager... Any way around it?... I have tried persistence as well. That too says ERROR in script: operation failed: Access denied?... Any help would be grateful..

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to install a backdoor on a windows 8/8.1/10 machine. You will always get access denied , since after windows 7 they have made patch around it, only administrator can get this access. And as far as I know there is no simple way to get the admin access on a windows 8 and afterwards machine with metasploit.

Answer (score 0):

just got mine to work. run the payload first used to access the target maching as administrator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).